# Sequelize order by column does not order the rows

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want to order by the `updatedAt` time, so that I can show posts that are updated recently on the top.
Here is my query-

```
const post = await Post.findAndCountAll({
    attributes: {
      exclude: ["description"],
    },
    where: { isVisible: true },
    limit: 10,
    offset: 1,
    order: [["updatedAt", "DESC"]],
  });
```

This is not ordering the posts. What am I missing?

Documentation that I referred to - [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html)

Edit: Post Model-

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  return sequelize.define("Post", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    briefDescription: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(300),
      allowNull: false,
      validate: { len: [1, 300] },
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    },
    url: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    thumbnail: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    sourceText: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    sourceUrl: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    priority: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 1,
      validate: {
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
      },
    },
    isFeatured: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
    likeCount: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0,
    },
    commentCount: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0,
    },
    moodCount: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0,
    },
    moodJSON: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: JSON.stringify(
        ["HAPPY", "MOTIVATED", "NORMAL", "SAD", "MEH"].map((rxn) => {
          return { mood: rxn, count: 0 };
        })
      ),
    },
    bookmarkCount: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0,
    },
    viewCount: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0,
    },
    shareCount: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0,
    },
    isSpam: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
    isVisible: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: Could you add the code of the `Post` model?

Comment: @oniramarf I updated my question with the `Post` model

Comment: Can you try adding all the column names except `description` in the attributes? Because mentioning what column to be ordered inside the attributes works in my case.